# A simple NP-hard problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I'm reading this paper, [A simple NP-hard problem by Demontis](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1556167), where he defines an interesting $NP$-hard set and finally he conclude with this theorem:

> Theorem: $P=NP$  if and only if it is possible to calculate in polynomial time all the
>   fundamental elements of any formula.

The paper does not have an abstract and I'm kind of lost because of the new terminology used in the paper.

> Could you explain the significance of this paper? Do the fundamental elements of a formula represent the variables that have true value in every satisfying assignment? Does this theorem represent a new result? What are the insights into the $P$ vs $NP$ problem presented in the paper?

ACM SIGACT News, Volume 40 Issue 2, June 2009

Comment: Are questions of the form "Could you explain the significance of paper X" on-topic here? In particular, if X isn't a peer-reviewed scientific article? People could generate thousands of such questions, and each of them would be of very little interest to the users of this site.

Comment: @Jukka, As far as I know, ACM SIGACT News is peer-reviewed. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jukka, Are you suggesting that questions regarding ACM SIGACT News articles are off-topic?

Comment: SIGACT News may not be peer-reviewed to the same extent that J.ACM is, but articles in it are certainly supposed to be screened adequately enough that they are not complete nonsense. So I think this question is on-topic. I have to admit I can't follow that paper either, although I haven't tried that hard.

Comment: @Turkistany, as for your last question, if this article presented any real new insight into the P vs NP question, it would almost certainly have appeared in a more prestigious publication than SIGACT News.

Comment: Thanks Peter for clarifying it. My gut feeling tells me there is something original in this paper. I could be wrong.